# Pandas extrac number with a decimal operator afer $ from a string

Tags: python, regex, pandas

also there are several [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61897051/pandas-extract-number-with-decimals-from-string) to that, I am still not able to solve my issue.

I have a pandas column from a poker game and want to analyze the pot size out of it, therefore I need to extract the number (with a . decimalseperator) after a `$`. The column looks like this:

```
Action
Player (8, 5) won the $5.40 main pot with a Straight
...
Player (A, 2) won the $21.00 main pot with a flush
...
```

when i run: `df['number'] = df['action'].str.extract('([0-9][,.]*[0-9]*)')`
it doesn't give me the expected outcome the outcome shold be:

```
number
5.40
...
21.00
```

Comment: Like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51905346/how-to-extract-dollar-amount-from-pandas-dataframe-column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'action':['Player (8, 5) won the $5.40 main pot with a Straight','Player (A, 2) won the $21.00 main pot with a flush']})
>>> df['action'].str.extract(r'\$(\d+(?:[,.]\d+)*)', expand=False)
0     5.40
1    21.00
Name: Action, dtype: object
```

The `\$(\d+(?:[,.]\d+)*)` pattern matches a literal `$` symbol, and then captures into Group 1 any one or more digits and then zero or more sequences of a `,` or `.` and then one or more digits.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/80hlH5/2).